# スクロールするとページが縦に揺れます

Tags: javascript, html, html5

スクロールすると各要素が縦に揺れます。
各要素を一つずつ消してみても、揺れはなおりませんでした。
ページはこちらです。
https://unagi-ryousin.com/
現象の確認方法としては、下にスクロールさせてから上にすぐ戻すと、ページが縦に揺れます。特に「量深の人気商品」より下の、商品が並んでいる辺りの画像の部分をスクロールしてみると分かりやすいです。TOPページのみ発生しています。

直接関係ないかもしれませんが、
Chrome DevToolsに下記の警告が出ています。
Each dictionary in the list "icons" should contain a non-empty UTF8 string field "type".
下記に同じ内容のページがありますが、iconsで検索しても該当の項目は見つかりません。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171107/each-dictionary-in-the-list-icons-should-contain-a-non-empty-utf8-string-field

Comment: 単にページの URL を指し示すだけではなく、問題の再現する (最小限の) コードを質問中に直接含めてください。

Comment: @cubick　様
ありがとうございます。原因が特定できていないため、該当のコードをお伝えするのが難しいです。現象の確認方法としては、下にスクロールさせてから上にすぐ戻すと、ページが縦に揺れます。特に商品が並んでいる辺りの画像の部分をスクロールしてみると分かりやすいです。

Comment: 現象が再現されるまでコードを絞っていくデバック作業をしてみてはいかがでしょうか？まずはフルフルのHTMLとCSSとjavascriptから、DOM要素を減らしていったり、関係ないと思われるJavascriptを除外して、動作がどのソースを削除すると発生しなくなるかミニマムなソースの作成を目指してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードが長大すぎて読めていないのですが、 ヘッダーが消えている状態のとき、 `position` プロパティの値が `absolute` や `fixed` ではなくなっているのではないでしょうか？もしそうならば、ヘッダーの表示が切り替わるようなスクロールをするたびに、ヘッダー分の高さだけ文書全体がずれる動作になります。

Comment: @keitaro_so 様、ありがとうございます。仰っている意味が理解できました。DOM要素を減らしてみると、おそらくヘッダが影響していることがわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @supa 様、ありがとうございます。ヘッダーが影響していることが分かってきました。ヘッダーを透過にして、TOP画像をページの上まで表示させると現象が再現しなくなりました。おっしゃる通りの現象が起きているようです。ヘッダーの表示が切り替わる設定について、どのソースを見るべきかこちらを参考に探してみます。https://coco-factory.jp/ugokuweb/move01/5-1-9/

Comment: @supa 様、ヘッダーに当たっているCSSのクラス名を探しましたが見つからず、Shopifyのテーマを利用しているのですが変更できないようです。私にこれ以上対処できないので透過にすると現象が再現しないというご提案をしてみます。ご意見いただきありがとうございました。